special characters in Delphi TRESTClient request wrongly displayed
I have a problem with special characters like ä, ö, ü, etc. getting displayed as � in my requests.
I send the request like so:
var
  RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
  RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
  lBody: string;

lBody := '{"value": "testäöü"}';
RESTClient1 := TRESTClient.Create(myUrl);
RESTRequest1 := TRESTRequest.Create(RESTClient1);
RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + mySessionId, pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8', pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Body', lBody, pkREQUESTBODY, [poDoNotEncode]);
RESTRequest1.Execute;

if RESTRequest1.Response.StatusCode <> 200 then
begin
  // raise Exception
end;

If I look at lBody in the debugger the characters are displayed correctly, however the receiving REST server (and fiddler when inspected) wrongly display my JSON: {"value": "test���"}.

Instead use the following to add the body:
RESTRequest1.AddBody(lBody, 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

